# how to change path of iOS file to show project path

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

To manually include a number of “library” files into  my project, I open my project in xCode. And then I open the “library” folder in finder. Then I drag and dropped from the folder into my project. But now when I go to `Buid Phases > Compile Sources` I see the path of the files I just copied to be `…/download/…` instead of `/project/...`. This is bad because when I push to git, the files aren’t passed along and they look red on the computer of anyone else who sync, for the obvious reason that the path specified does not exist on their machines. How do I fix this? As in, when I drag and drop I was expecting for the files to be copied and not just referenced. But they weren’t. Is there a simple fix? Note: I mark “copy items into destination group’s folder (if needed)”.

Also when I open my project in finder, the group that is supposed to have the "library" files isn't in there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. But I can assure you it is human error (well, I think anyway). Do this:

Right click on the group and select "show in finder". You will see that the group belongs somewhere else. So as long as you keep adding to the group, it won't really ever show up in your project. To fix, delete the whole group, type the group by hand, and then try drag and drop again.